# How to retrieve same column twice from one table with Where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am trying to retrieve a column twice from one table for ex:

```
select M.Event_Name as 'Male',
       F.Event_Name as 'Female' 
from   Table1 M, Table1 F
where  M.Gender = 'M'
       and F.Gender = 'F'
       and F.Country = 12
       and M.Country = 12
```

Table1 data

```
ID    Event_Name   Gender  Country
1     Cricket      M       12
2     FootBall     M       13
3     BasketBall   M       12
4     Hockey       M       12
5     Tennis       M       13
6     Volly Ball   M       13
7     Cricket      F       13
8     FootBall     F       13
9     BasketBall   F       12
10    Hockey       F       13
11    Tennis       F       12
12    Volly Ball   F       12
```

**What I Got is :**

```
Male           Female
Cricket        Tennis
Cricket        BasketBall
Cricket        Volly ball
BasketBall     Tennis
BasketBall     BasketBall
BasketBall     Volly ball
Hockey         Tennis
Hockey         BasketBall
Hockey         Volly ball
```

**Expecting:**

```
Male          Female
Cricket       Tennis
BasketBall    BasketBall
Hockey        Volly ball
```

Help me out.. Thanks

Comment: I really dislike the "urgency" pleas.

Comment: You haven't explained your logic or shown all the data needed for your query: what is the `Place` column that you've referenced in your query?

Comment: Please set up an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with some example data!

Comment: You need to provide sample data of the underlying table, the result is not enough.

Comment: What kind o relation are you trying to build with your expected output? Right now to me it appears random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use something like this which incorporates a `PIVOT`:

```
select M as Male, 
  F as Female
from
(
  select event_name, gender,
    row_number() over(partition by gender, country order by id) rn
  from yourtable
  where gender in ('M', 'F')
    and country = 12
) src
pivot
(
  max(event_name)
  for gender in (M, F)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7124d/6)

Or you can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement:

```
select 
  max(case when gender = 'M' then event_name end) male,
  max(case when gender = 'F' then event_name end) female
from
(
  select event_name, gender,
      row_number() over(partition by gender, country order by id) rn
  from yourtable 
  where gender in ('M', 'F')
    and country = 12
) src
group by rn
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7124d/10)

Both produce the same result:

```
|       MALE |     FEMALE |
---------------------------
|    Cricket | BasketBall |
| BasketBall |     Tennis |
|     Hockey | Volly Ball |
```

Comment: ahh Pivoting....Thanks a lot... I am in a hurry so cudn't post the question properly...