# Pivot dynamic column

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a table with the following values.

```
Date                     TCOUNT      COUNT
02/06/2013 00:00        3500        35
02/12/2013 00:00        4000        23
02/21/2013 00:00        1000        54
02/27/2013 00:00        5000        12
```

where `Date` is dynamic col need to be pivoted.

I need to pivote the above table to get the below result

```
02/06/2013 00:00    02/12/2013 00:00    02/21/2013 00:00    02/27/2013 00:00
35                  23                  54                  12
3500                4000                1000                5000
```

please help.

Thanks.

Comment: **WHAT** database system/product/RDBMS ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the fact that your [previous question was tagged with sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807541/how-to-retrieve-same-column-twice-from-one-table-with-where-condition), I am guessing that you need sql server syntax.

In order to get the result, you will need to use both the `UNPIVOT` and the `PIVOT` functions. The unpivot will take the `TCount` and `Count` columns and convert them to rows and then the `PIVOT` will take the `dates` and convert them to columns.

If you know the values ahead of time then you can hard-code the query:

```
select *
from
(
  select date, value, col
  from yourtable
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (tcount, count)
  ) unpiv
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for date in ([2013-02-06], [2013-02-12], 
               [2013-02-21], [2013-02-27])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2c047/7)

However, if you have an unknown number of dates, then you will need dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), Date, 120)) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT col, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select convert(varchar(10), Date, 120) date, 
                  value, col
                from yourtable
                unpivot
                (
                  value
                  for col in (tcount, count)
                ) unpiv
            ) src
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for date in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2c047/6)

The result of both is:

```
|    COL | 2013-02-06 | 2013-02-12 | 2013-02-21 | 2013-02-27 |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|  COUNT |         35 |         23 |         54 |         12 |
| TCOUNT |       3500 |       4000 |       1000 |       5000 |
```

Comment: Why, oh why, can't Microsoft give us true dynamic pivoting? Blearg.

Comment: @ErikE I will jump for joy when that happens.

Comment: It's probably due to complex engine internals that mere mortals cannot comprehend without an endowment of wit straight from the gods.

Comment: No, it's due to relational theory, in which the columns in a given query's result set are fixed.  The values found in matching rows cannot magically add columns.  Relational theory is widely understood, without divine intervention.  :-)